# Javascript equivilent of Python's include

Tags: javascript

I'm hunting for the equivalent of Python's import statement.

I'd love for the following to work:

```
<head>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function useBar(){
            alert(foo.bar());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onClick="useBar();">Bar</button>
```

What would foo.js look like, and would I have to do anything additional in the html page to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `python's import`, right?

If you want namespaces, you can do something like that in `foo.js`.

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() {

    },
    baz: function() {

    }
};
```

Comment: yes, import. PHP, Python. I mix them up in the morning sometimes, thanks.

Comment: Actually, you should use `require` instead of `include` in PHP ;)

Comment: Also helpful is saying <script src="foo.js"> rather then source="foo.js"

Answer (score 0):

`foo.js` contains a portion of js code (functions, objects, plain code). Whin this file was loaded throught `<script type="text/javascript" source="foo.js"></script>` all of its code now available across page.

Answer (score 0):

foo.js would be just a regular javascript file, with functions and/or variables, with no <script> tags, nothing else required.